# Grails behavior difference between run-app and run-war

Tags: grails, groovy, bootstrapping, metaclass, expandometaclass

I'm relatively new to Groovy and Grails and am trying them out in my spare time.  I've got a small test Grails application that I'm able to run fine using `grails run-app`, but `grails run-war` results in an error.

In the `grails-app/conf/BootStrip.init` method, I'm adding some property getters onto the `DefaultGrailsControllerClass` and `DefaultGrailsApplication`:

```
DefaultGrailsControllerClass.metaClass.getMenuText = { ->
    getPropertyOrStaticPropertyOrFieldValue('menuText', String.class)
}
DefaultGrailsControllerClass.metaClass.getMenuOrder = { ->
    getPropertyOrStaticPropertyOrFieldValue('menuOrder', Integer.class)
}
DefaultGrailsApplication.metaClass.getMenuControllerClasses = { ->
    controllerClasses.findAll { it.menuText != null }.sort { it.menuOrder }
}
```

In my `grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp`, I'm using this:

```
<g:each var="c" in="${ grailsApplication.menuControllerClasses }">
    <li><g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.menuText}</g:link></li>
</g:each>
```

This works fine under `run-app`, but running it under `run-war`, I get the following:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: menuControllerClasses for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication
```

I've tried this under Grails 1.1.1 and 1.2-M1 and get the same result.  I've verified that the `BootStrap.init` method is being called (via a `println`), but the changes made to the `metaClass` don't appear to take under `run-war`.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

grails run-war -- Run's a Grails application's WAR in Jetty

grails run-app -- Runs a Grails application in Jetty

The difference seems to be that run-war does not support reloading as run-app does.

Not sure what you are missing.

Comment: I've read somewhere that `run-app` uses Tomcat starting from Grails 1.3.